# Масштабирование 2D камеры SDL2 C++

Tags: c++, камера, 2d, sdl

С перемещением камеры в *мире* проблем не было (просто оффсетим *x* и *y*), но систему масштабирования не знаю как сделать.

Рендер всех текстур (объектов) происходит так:

```
void Texture::render(SDL_Rect sprite_rect, SDL_Rect world_rect) {
    world_rect.x -= camera.offset_x;
    world_rect.y -= camera.offset_y;
    SDL_RenderCopy(_Renderer, texture, &sprite_rect, &world_rect);
}
```

Comment: Ну если *что-то* не получается, то надо *что-то* подправить.

Answer (score -1):

тебе нужна эта функция http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx она тебе позволит масштабировать изображение) высчитываешь координаты по формуле vX =  (x - camera.position.x) / camera.size.x;